# declareMock<> not working with mockk in android unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, koin, mockk

i am trying to mock a repository class using `declareMock` and `mockk` but it doesn't seem to be working as i am getting the data from the real repository.

**Version**

```
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:2.1.6"
testImplementation "org.koin:koin-test:2.1.6"
```

**Code**

My application class (only relevant parts):

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    companion object {
        val appModule = module {
            single<RepositoryUserLists> { RepositoryUserListsImpl() }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startKoin {
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(this@MyApplication)
            modules(appModule)
        }
    }
}
```

My test class (only relevant parts)

```
class TestRepositoryUserLists : KoinTest {
    @get:Rule
    val koinTestRule = KoinTestRule.create {
        modules(MyApplication.appModule)
    }

    @get:Rule
    val mockProvider = MockProviderRule.create { clazz ->
        mockkClass(clazz.java.kotlin)
    }

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private val repo: RepositoryUserLists by inject()

    @Before
    fun before() {
        declareMock<RepositoryUserLists> {
            every { getAllLists() } returns MutableLiveData(listOf(MyList("test list")))
        }
    
        //PROBLEM IS HERE
        //Expected: a list containing one item names "test list".
        //Actual: empty list (like in real repository).
        repo.getAllLists().value 
    }
}
```

github issue: https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/841

Answer (score 1):

Just posted it here for those migrating to a newer version of the koin like 2.2.2,
and the dependency test was failed with an error `Missing MockProvider. Please use MockProvider.register() to register a new mock provider`.

```kotlin
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockkClass
...

val app = koinApplication {
    printLogger(Level.DEBUG)
    modules(...)
}

MockProvider.register { mockkClass(it) }

with(app.koin) {
    declareMock<MyService> {
        every { someAction() } returns "some answer"
        ...
    }
}

app.checkModules()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `given/will` syntax inside the `declareMock` block

```
    declareMock<RepositoryUserLists> {
        given(getAllLists()).willReturn(MutableLiveData(listOf(MyList("test list"))))
    }
```

Comment: this is not the syntax for `mockk`

Comment: I believe that is the whole point. Koin uses the `mockProvider` *you* provide and mocks it for you. Therefore, inside `declareMock` you need to use the koin mock functions.

Comment: i got io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: RepositoryUserLists(#1).getAllLists()

Comment: I am not sure if it helps but in my project instead of a Rule I use `startKoin`. Maybe something like this works?
`startKoin { modules(MyApplication.appModule) }`

Comment: thanks for the comment, but for now i just use a fake repository which i managed to inject. ill try this when i feel like trying this again